# Will I be charged for the test users I create using google-admin-sdk?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

With Google Apps I have to pay for each user account. At which point does this charge happen? I want to test my project against 1000 users to see how it handles the load, but I don't want my program to create 1000 users if I'm going to be charged.

Is there a developer sandbox where any number of users can be created freely?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will be charged. But the billing is on a daily basis.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/1247362?hl=en

Note that we will prorate the number of seats for partial months of usage. So, for example, if you add a user on April 1 and delete them on April 15, we will charge you for only half a month of usage.